# AngularUI - UI Bootstrap Datepicker date on view and in the value are different

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I have a problem with `Uib Datepicker`. I have to dynamically change date format. for example:

```html
 <input type="text" 
                        class="form-control" 
                        ng-model="field.value" 
                        ng-value="field.value" 
                        name="{{field.name}}" 
                        uib-datepicker-popup="dateFormat"  // I could be yy-MM and other
                        is-open="openedStart" 
                        datepicker-options="dateOptions" 
                        show-button-bar="false"
                        show-weeks="false"
                        ng-click="openedStart = !openedStart"
                        />
```

In the calendar view it's shown good, as I want, for example `"16-05"` as it was inserted `"yy-MM"`, but to the backend goes `value: "2016-05-02T21:00:00.000Z"` which is stores in the `ng-value`.

How to fix it and send to the backend the same value as in the view?

Answer (score 0):

The datepicker directive requires the ng-model value to be a JavaScript date object (like the Angular input - date directive).  If you need to send the date as "yy-MM" to a service, you can format it using the Angular date [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).  The date filter will also work if your displaying the ng-model value to another part of your view.

Comment: Hi! I've already tried like this: ng-value="field.value | date: dateFormat" dateFormat = yy-MM. But it doesn't  work